# Best way to handle a large list of data loading into a List View with regularly repopulating it for search's

Tags: c#, .net, list, performance, listview

I am curious if there is a more efficient or quicker way to implement what I am doing. I have a list with around 5 thousand items.

after adding any filtering to my list of data I create a list of ListViewItems

```
public void CreateListViewData()
    {
        _listViewItems = new List<ListViewItem>();
        foreach (Record record in _filteredRecords)
        {                
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
                {                        
                    Record.Name.ToUpper(),
                    Record.Reference.ToUpper(),
                    Record.Status.ToString()
                }) 
                { Name = Record.Reference.ToUpper() };
            _listViewItems.Add(item);
        }

    }
```

Then I add these to my List View:

```
private void PopulateListView()
    {
        ListView.IfInvokeRequired(() =>
        {
            ListView.BeginUpdate();
            ListView.Items.Clear();
            ListView.Items.AddRange(_listViewItems.ToArray());
            ListView.EndUpdate();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is your current implementation has any issue? Please elaborate on those issues.

Comment: @LouisGo My issue is its speed I would like to find out if there is a faster more efficient way to do what I have implemented above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3137831/4123703 Is this answering your question?